# parse google maps API

Tags: xml, maps

can't seem to get this parser to work for google maps, I think its because there is no xml extension? It works on a xml file that I make, but when I use google xml it doesn't seem to want to grab it.

```
<?php
$address = 'edgemont dr wyoming, MI';
$address = rawurlencode ($address);

$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
$link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>';
echo $link;

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// get Latitude from XML
$lat=$xml->GeocodeResponse->result->geometry->location->lat;
echo $lat;

?>
```

Comment: $url returns http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=amsterdam&sensor=false. however, $lat returns nothing at all. I am developing locally via XAMPP. doubt this is the issue though?

Comment: Sorry wasn't asking what is in the $url but what is in the $xml

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=edgemont%20dr%20wyoming%2C%20MI&sensor=false is what is returned. that is the xml, click the link you can view it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change this:

```
// get Latitude from XML
$lat=$xml->GeocodeResponse->result->geometry->location->lat;
echo $lat;
```

to this

```
// get Latitude from XML
$lat=$xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
echo $lat;
```

Answer (score -1):

normally, google API's require an API key. I am not seeing where you are adding that to your request. when I manually construct your api call and past it into my browser, i get this: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=edgemont%20dr%20wyoming%2C%20MI and google returns a "Request Denied".

you can [go here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html) to get a Google Maps API key.  That said, there are many many many other geo-coders out there. some require some type of registration and/or payment and others do not.

[here](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=free%20geocoder%20services) is a google of "Free GeoCoder services"

Comment: Google no longer requires an api registration key in v3 of the api. It does require a sensor=false (or true) in the querystring which is why your example gives a request denied. Try http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=amsterdam&sensor=false which works fine

Comment: huh? sensor=false is there. your browser might be cutting off the code, scroll to the right. at least in my example, Muad'Dib forgot it in his example.

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=edgemont%20dr%20wyoming%2C%20MI&sensor=false is what $url returns.

Comment: my example was copied from the url the OP created. yes, the parameter is missing, but i did not forget anything.